# Why is partition data shared when I use redis connection pool?

Tags: python, redis

my config
python = 3.8
redis =  4.6.0
**I'm trying redis connection pool。

If I don't use the redis pool there is no problem, I don't know where the problem is
**

If there is something wrong with my code, please advise。

```
import redis
from pottery import Redlock

from config import CONFIG
from config.argparse_info import args_dict

ENV = args_dict["env"]
ENV = "dev"


class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = CONFIG.get("redis", f"{ENV}_host")
        self.port = CONFIG.getint("redis", f"{ENV}_port")
        self.password = CONFIG.get("redis", f"{ENV}_password", fallback=None)


class MyRedis(Base):
    _pool = None

    def __init__(self, db=0):
        super().__init__()
        if not MyRedis._pool:
            MyRedis._pool = redis.ConnectionPool(
                host=self.host,
                port=self.port,
                password=self.password,
                db=db,
                decode_responses=True,
                max_connections=1000,
                socket_timeout=10,
                socket_keepalive=True,
                retry_on_timeout=True
            )
        self.r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=MyRedis._pool)


if "__main__" == __name__:

    r_0 = MyRedis(0).r
    # r_0.flushall()
    r_0.set("1", 111111, ex=600)
    r_2 = MyRedis(2).r
    r_2.set("2", 22222, ex=600)
    print(r_0.get("1"))
    print(r_2.get("2"))

    print(r_0.get("2"))
    print(r_2.get("1"))
```

**my result
111111
22222
22222
111111**

I want output

111111
22222
None
None

It's ok for me to use this method

```
import redis


def rr(db):
    r = redis.Redis(db=db, host='****', port=6666, decode_responses=True, password="****")
    return r


r0 = rr(0)
r0.flushall()
r0.set("a", "11111", ex=100)
r2 = rr(2)
r2.set("b", "44444", ex=100)
print(r0.get("a"))
print(r2.get("b"))

print(r0.get("b"))
print(r2.get("a"))

my result 
11111
44444
None
None
```